# MySQL delete hanging

Tags: mysql

I am running a basic delete from mysql.  There are no foreign keys, nothing is accessing the table other than the delete I am running.

```
delete from database.table 
where filename='roger.doc' 
and aisle='whatever' 
and filetime='2022-07-09 18:37:13.645050';
```

MYSQL is just hanging, how can I get past this or force a delete?

Error I am getting is

> Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`.

I think the lock wait is 3 minutes.  However there are no locks using `show engine innodb status\G` the latest deadlock was 10 days ago on a completely different db and table.

I have added the primary key which is the `filetime` and an additional key which is `aisle` and the delete still hangs.  I have to manually delete the rows before then the rows after then delete the problem row and that has worked.  But the delete script just hangs.

Using explain gives me the following.

```
1 | DELETE      | data_management | NULL       | range | PRIMARY,aisle_index,date_index | PRIMARY | 7       | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using where |
```

Comment: is `filename` an indexed column on the `table`?

Comment: no it is not indexed. The script has been working for years with filename not having an index. The delete query is using a key along with filename.  `delete from database.table where filename='roger.doc' and aisle='whatever';`  The aisle is a key in the table.

Comment: Do you need an `AND` between `filename='roger.doc'` and `aisle='whatever'`

Comment: Sorry I fixed the `and` issue.  It was a typo.

Comment: If you're not sure what the lock wait is, set the lock wait time to 100 seconds with `set innodb_lock_wait_timeout=100;`. The try the `show engine innodb status\G` command again within 100 seconds of triggering the lock.

Comment: You said that you have created indexes on `filetime` and `aisle` fields. In your condition, the `filename` field is also used. Does this index (`CREATE INDEX x ON tbl(filename ,aisle ,filetime`) exist in your table?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to replication.  One of the nodes is refusing to accept the transactions from lead node.  So it is just halting the system.

Answer (score 0):

Some other thread on the system is holding a lock on the table.
This can be caused by a number of issues. You should run SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
to find the thread that has a lock on the table.
Once you identify it (it maybe a thread started by another user - either directly or as part of a stored program with a definer security profile), you will need to kill that thread.